What is the difference between software development and software engineering?
What is the difference between software development and software engineering?
And What are the foundations of each one of them?

these aren't scientific terms, so everyone uses them whatever they like. you may consider them synonyms unless the author explicitly specifies what each term means in her speech

@Bulat Thank you for your comment.
So what are the foundations of programming in general that I can learn before I specialize?

more suitable for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/
